# Remove dead pixel from video material (not screen)

Tags: video, ffmpeg

My camera recently ran through some trouble and now my *sensor* chip has four dead pixels, spread across the screen. *(Yes, it's **actually** the censor, I've quadruple checked. It's not the screen.)*
So there are some dead pixels on all my footage now.

*If it matters, my footage is in the following format*

```
Resolution: 1920x1090
Frame rate: 29.970030
Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
Decoded format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV full scale
```

Is there any known approach to removing these?

(I was thinking of some sort of program to which I manually pass the positions of the dead pixels and it then replaces them by an average of the surrounding pixels. Some `ffmpeg` filter maybe?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [delogo filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#delogo) with `ffmpeg` or `ffplay`. Instead of re-encoding, you can just filter upon playback:

[image][image]
<sub>Before and after delogo.</sub>

## Example: playback

```
ffplay -vf \
"delogo=x=10:y=120:w=1:h=1, \
 delogo=x=862:y=438:w=1:h=1, \
 delogo=x=56:y=207:w=1:h=1, \
 delogo=x=1259:y=943:w=1:h=1" \
input.mp4
```

## Example: encoding

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf \
"delogo=x=10:y=120:w=1:h=1, \
 delogo=x=862:y=438:w=1:h=1, \
 delogo=x=56:y=207:w=1:h=1, \
 delogo=x=1259:y=943:w=1:h=1" \
-c:a copy cleaned-output.mp4
```

- Results may vary, and I did not investigate why delogo caused a slight washed out look in my example.
- You can extract an image from the video (`ffmpeg -i input -ss 5 -vframes 1 output.png`) and import it into the GIMP to find the pixel x,y locations.

Comment: +1 for the GIMP idea, that helps a lot. With the given Footage I did not experience any washout either.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, I think you can use `avidemux` with a "delogo" filter. Though with the pixels far apart, you'll need multiple runs, and there might be better options.

Comment: Great suggestion with the `delogo` but @LordNeckbeard's solution (with `ffmpeg` instead of `avidemux`) is more suitable for me because I can filter multiple points at the same time and it's scriptable, so I can run it on a all of my footage automatically.